# Powershell, how to capture argument(s) of Select-String and include with matched output

Tags: powershell, select-string

Thanks to @mklement0 for the help with getting this far with answer given in [Powershell search directory for code files with text matching input a txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886276/powershell-search-directory-for-code-files-with-text-matching-input-a-txt-file?noredirect=1#comment111224650_62886276).

The below Powershell works well for finding the occurrences of a long list of database field names in a source code folder.

```
$inputFile = 'C:\DataColumnsNames.txt'
$outputFile = 'C:\DataColumnsUsages.txt'
Get-ChildItem C:\ProjectFolder -Filter *.cs -Recurse -Force -ea SilentlyContinue |
  Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content $inputFile) | 
    Select-Object Path, LineNumber, line | 
      Export-csv $outputfile
```

However, many lines of source code have multiple matches, especially ADO.NET SQL statements with a lot of field names on one line. If the field name argument was included with the matching output the results will be more directly useful with less additional massaging such as lining up everything with the original field name list. For example if there is a source line "BatchId = NewId" it will match field name list item "BatchId". Is there an easy way to include in the output both "BatchId" and "BatchId = NewId"?

Played with the matches object but it doesn't seem to have the information.  Also tried Pipeline variable like here but X is null.

```
$inputFile = 'C:\DataColumnsNames.txt'
$outputFile = 'C:\DataColumnsUsages.txt'
Get-ChildItem C:\ProjectFolder -Filter *.cs -Recurse -Force -ea SilentlyContinue |
  Select-String -Pattern (Get-Content $inputFile -PipelineVariable x) | 
    Select-Object $x, Path, LineNumber, line | 
      Export-csv $outputile
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) outputs have **a `Pattern` property that reflects the specific pattern among the (potential) *array* of patterns passed to `-Pattern` that matched *on a given line***.

The **caveat** is that **if *multiple* patterns match, `.Pattern` only reports the pattern among those that matched that is listed *first* among them *in the `-Pattern` argument***.

Here's a simple example, using an array of strings to simulate lines from files as input:

```
'A fool and',
'his barn',
'are soon parted.',
'foo and bar on the same line' | 
  Select-String -Pattern ('bar', 'foo') | 
    Select-Object  Line, LineNumber, Pattern
```

The above yields:

```
Line                         LineNumber Pattern
----                         ---------- -------
A fool and                            1 foo
his barn                              2 bar
foo and bar on the same line          4 bar
```

Note how `'bar'` is listed as the `Pattern` value for the last line, even though `'foo'` appeared first in the *input line*, because `'bar'` comes before `'foo'` in the *pattern array*.

---

**To reflect the actual pattern that *appears first on the input line* in a `Pattern` property**, more work is needed:

- Formulate your array of patterns as a *single regex* using *alternation* (`|`), wrapped as a whole in a *capture group* (`(...)`) - e.g., `'(bar|foo)'`)

  - Note: The expression used below, `'({0})' -f ('bar', 'foo' -join '|')`, constructs this regex dynamically, *from an array* (the array literal `'bar', 'foo'` here, but you can substitute any array variable or even `(Get-Content $inputFile)`); if you want to treat the input patterns as *literals* and they happen to contain regex metacharacters (such as `.`), you'll need to escape them with `[regex]::Escape()` first.
- Use a calculated property to define a custom `Pattern` property that reports the capture group's value, which is the first among the values encountered on each input line:

```
'A fool and',
'his barn',
'are soon parted.',
'foo and bar on the same line' | 
  Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern ('({0})' -f ('bar', 'foo' -join '|')) | 
    Select-Object Line, LineNumber, 
                  @{ n='Pattern'; e={ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value } }
```

This yields (abbreviated to show only the last match):

```
Line                         LineNumber Pattern
----                         ---------- -------
...

foo and bar on the same line          4 foo
```

Now, `'foo'` is properly reported as the matching pattern.

---

To **report *all* patterns found on each line**:

- Switch `-AllMatches` is required to tell `Select-String` to find *all* matches on each line, represented in the `.Matches` collection of the `MatchInfo` output objects.
- The `.Matches` collection must then be enumerated (via the `.ForEach()` collection method) to extract the capture-group value from each match.

```
'A fool and',
'his barn',
'are soon parted.',
'foo and bar on the same line' | 
  Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern ('({0})' -f ('bar', 'foo' -join '|')) | 
    Select-Object Line, LineNumber, 
                  @{ n='Pattern'; e={ $_.Matches.ForEach({ $_.Groups[1].Value }) } }
```

This yields (abbreviated to show only the last match):

```
Line                         LineNumber Pattern
----                         ---------- -------
...

foo and bar on the same line          4 {foo, bar}
```

Note how *both* `'foo'` and `'bar'` are now reported in `Pattern`, in the order encountered on the line.

Comment: Letting you know @mklement0 your answer was what I needed to figure out the rest of my requirement. I have posted my final script as an answer.  Thanks again, now a Powershell toddler versus new born.

Answer (score 0):

The solid information and examples from @mklement0 were enough to point me in the right direction for researching and understanding more about Powershell and the object pipeline and calculated properties.

I was able to finally achieve my goals of a cross referencing a list of table and field names to the C# code base.The input file is simply table and field names, pipe delimited.  (one of the glitches I had was not using pipe in the split, it was a visual error that took awhile to finally see, so check for that). The output is the table name, field name, code file name, line number and actual line.  It's not perfect but much better than manual effort for a few hundred fields!  And now there are possibilities for further automation in the data mapping and conversion project.  Thought about using C# utility programming but that might have taken just as long to figure out and implement and much more cumbersome that a working Powershell.

The key for me at this point is "working"!  My first deeper dive into the abstruse world of Powershell.  The key points of my solution are the use of the calculated property to get the table and field names in the output, realization that expressions can be used in certain places like to build a Pattern and that the pipeline is passing only certain specific objects after each command (maybe that is too restricted of a view but it's better than what I had before).

Hope this helps someone in future.  I could not find any examples close enough to get over the hump and so asked my first ever stackoverflow questions.

```
$inputFile = "C:\input.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\output.csv"
$results = Get-Content $inputfile
foreach ($i in $results) {
   Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\ProjectFolder"  -Filter *.cs  -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
   Select-String -Pattern  $i.Split('|')[1] |
    Select-Object   @{ n='Pattern'; e={ $i.Split('|')[0], $i.Split('|')[1]  -join '|'} },  Filename, LineNumber, line |
Export-Csv $outputFile -Append}
```