# Powershell search files with output item found and which filename

Tags: powershell

other question doesn't answer this question, that comes up blank.

I have an array of 8 items I need to search through more than 100 files.  So basically like a loop within a loop but with Powershell (newbie sorry).

I'm in the directory of the 100 files.  I have built so far:

```
Get-ChildItem -path . -name | Get-Content | Select-String -Pattern $data
```

which as far as I understand: gets the list of files, piped to Get-Content to read all the file data, piped to select the pattern of the array items.

Lots of data out ofcourse, Get-Content needs to not be filtered to search it, but I only need to know which $data item was a match, and in which file it was found.

I think it hits true but then gives the the full content of the search I can't tell.

Don't know if we can do this all one liner or if it needs to be a script.

Any help or pointers to same much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [proposed duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8153750/45375) answers *part* of your question, but not the following aspect (emphasis added):

> I only *need to know which `$data` item was a match*, and in which file it was found.

```bash
Get-ChildItem -File -LiteralPath . | 
  Select-String -List -Pattern $data |
  Select-Object Pattern, Path
```

- As in the accepted answer to the linked duplicate, you can pipe `Get-ChildItem` output *directly* to [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) for an efficient way to search the *content* of each input file.

  - Note: `Select-String` *itself* accepts file paths, via its `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` parameters; thus, `Select-String -Path * -List -Pattern $data` would work too (any *directories* among the matches are *quietly ignored*).
  - However, using output from a `Get-ChildItem` as input gives you more control over which files to search through, notably the ability to search *recursively* in a directory subtree (`-Recurse`).
- `-List` limits searching each file's content to (at most) *one* match.
- In the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo) instances that `Select-String` outputs, the `.Path` property reflects the full path of the input file at hand, and `.Pattern` reflects which of the patterns passed to `-Pattern` matched.

  - As for the logic of which of the patterns is considered the match reported in `.Pattern` in case *multiple* patterns match on a *single line*:

    - It is the one that comes first *in the `-Pattern` argument*, irrespective of which potential matches comes first *in a given input line* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62899693/45375) for details.

Comment: thanks so very much, key learning piece here was Select-Object then getting the pieces I wanted with Pattern and Path.  I'll still have to manually verify but a prelim finding can be at least made

Comment: Glad to hear it, @sf2k; my pleasure. Hope you can work out the rest.